# Tracking Profile Editor shows wrong version of an orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I try to set up BAM for my BizTalk orchestrations. Everything is OK except the 2 orchestrations which are shown incorrectly in Tracking Profile Editor. For example, I've added an Expression shape with logging stuff to the end of every orchestrations, redeployed the app.

After that I opened all my orchestration one by one to ensure that all of them have that logging expression. For my surprise 2 of them was not changed. Moreover all of those orchestrations reside in one DLL so it cannot be caching issue.

When I went further inspecting the issue I found out that if I rename the type of an orchestration (e.g. "SET_DATACHANGES" --> "SET_DATACHANGES_") it will be shown in TPE with correct, most recent version.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The Tracking Profile Editor may be loading an incorrect version of the assembly containing the Orchestration components, either from the GAC or from the file system.

Did you deploy your BizTalk application from within Visual Studio?  If so, did you also restart all relevant Host Instances?

Check that you don't have any previous versions of the compiled assembly sitting in a directory that the .Net assembly loader might include in its assembly resolution order.

Comment: As I've mentioned I keep all my orchestrations in one assembly. TPE shows correct versions of all but the two orchestrations. So it's not a cache or GAC issue. And yes, I restart all host instances, to be sure I even rebooted my machine but no luck

Comment: Not sure if this helps, as I don't have any further insights, but is it possible the BttDeploy process adds metadata about the Orchestration into the database?  Simply deploying the Orchestration assembly may not refresh the TPE version of this metadata.  Maybe try a BttDeploy /remove, then re-deploy?
Hope this helps.